# Remove "Google Drive" from Quick Access default options

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-10-quick-access

I am trying to completely remove every trace of this "Google Drive" folder on my computer (the folder is deleted) but upon resetting Quick access to default by deleting this file "C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\f01b4d95cf55d32a.automaticDestinations-ms" [it gets re-pinned to Quick access despite not existing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRVua.png).

I uninstalled the google drive application a while ago

Comment: i wouldn't be able to delete the folder if it was installed, anyway i updated the question

Comment: This shortcut is re-installed every time that Google Drive starts up, which is just after login. Are you asking for a way to keep Google Drive installed, but just wish to get rid of this icon?

Comment: no, the shortcut is "reinstalled" every time i reset the quick access section in my file explorer, i just want to make the "default" quick access not include this folder

Comment: Are there other accounts on this computer and is Google Drive perhaps installed in one of them?

Comment: @music2myear nope, this is the only account

Answer (score 5):

Google has finally added a setting in Drive for this.  In 'Preferences' click the gear to get to 'Settings' and there will be a toggle right under the drive letter dropdown.

[Google Drive Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QC61.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As long as Google Drive is installed, it will renew this icon
every time that it starts up, which is normally after the login.
To get rid of it permanently, you need change the permissions on
Quick Access so it cannot be modified, as described below.

This manipulation will freeze the Quick Access so Google Drive cannot
modify it, but this will also block any other program and also
yourself. You will need to be undo it whenever you need to modify
Quick access.

- Remove the icon from Quick access
- Navigate to `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations`
- Right-click the folder named `f01b4d95cf55d32a.automaticDestinations-ms`
- Select Properties
- Go to the Security tab
- Click the Edit button
- At the top half of the dialog, under "Group or user names",
  click "Administrators"
- At the bottom half of the dialog, check "Deny" next to "Write"
- Do the same for your own user account
- Press OK to close all windows.

To undo, uncheck "Deny".